# Some question in mind about a polynomial Q(t) is compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Actually it is the textbook question

Let $Q(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{p}a_{k}t^{k}$ be polynomial s.t $Q(1) \neq 0$. 
Let $E:banach~space$, and let $T \in L(E)$ Assume $Q(T) \in K(E)$

Prove that $dim(I-T) < \infty$, and $R(I-T)$ is closed

What can do first for do this??

Comment: could you explain to me a few insignificant details : $L(E)$ means the bounded operators $E \to E$ ? $K(E)$ means the compact and bounded operators $E \to E$ ? $Q(T) = \sum_k a_k t^k$ ? and $R(I-T)$ what is $R$ ? and $dim(I-T) < \infty$ : what is $dim$ ?

Comment: Sorry about that

L(E) is bounded linear operator : E -> E
K(E) is compact linear operator : E -> E
$R(I-T)$ is range of $I-T$
Q(t) is polynomial , $Q \in K(E)$
dim : dimension